# Why the value returned by a pthread is not same as passed to the thread function?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

What I understand [pthread_join manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) is my program should output the same value I supplied to `print_xs` but the output obtained is:

```
Message from printxs 11131 a
Message from printxs 11234 b
32766 -16
32766 0
```

The Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

typedef struct paramsThread{
        char c;
        int count;
} threadPara;

void* print_xs(void* unused){
        threadPara *tp = (threadPara *)unused;
        int i=tp->count;

        printf("Message from printxs %d %c\n", tp->count, tp->c);
        return (void*)tp;
}

int main(){
        pthread_t thread1, thread2;
        threadPara t1,t2,t3,t4;
        t1.c = 'a';
        t2.c = 'b';
        t1.count = 11131;
        t2.count = 11234;
        t3.count=0;
        pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &print_xs, &t1);
        pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &print_xs, &t2);
        pthread_join(thread1,(void*)&t3);
        printf("%d %d\n", t3.count, t3.c);
        pthread_join(thread2,(void*)&t4);
        printf("%d %d\n", t4.count, t4.c);
        return 0;
}
```

Can some one explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [read a `pthread_join` reference or manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) you will see that the second argument is a pointer *to a pointer*. This is a way to emulate *pass by reference* in C.

The pointer the thread function returns is copied into another pointer.

The solution is to use pointers for `t3` and `t4` instead:

```
threadPara t1, t2;
threadPara *t3, *t4;

// ...

pthread_join(thread1,(void**)&t3);  // Pass pointer to the pointer, emulating pass by reference
printf("%d %d\n", t3->count, t3->c);
pthread_join(thread2,(void**)&t4);
printf("%d %d\n", t4->count, t4->c);
```

If you print the pointers, or use a debugger, then you will see that `t3` will be pointing to `t1` (i.e. `t3 == &t1`) and the same for `t4` and `t2`.

Comment: getting this error 
In file included from threadprog.c:2:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:261:12: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘struct threadPara **’
 extern int pthread_join (pthread_t __th, void **__thread_return);
            ^
Does that mean I have to create a void pointer>then receive the returned value>typecast > use ??

Comment: @PrinceRachit And how do you think that problem should be solved? Read the error message until you figure it out. (And yes I made a mistake in my answer)

Comment: Yeah corrected it. And I notice you have also updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The thread function returns an address, a `void*`.

[`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) receives this address *to* where its 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter (a `void**`) *points* to.

So to make use of this in your code instead of

```
        pthread_join(thread1, (void*)&t3);
```

do

```
        {
          void * pv;
          pthread_join(thread1, &pv);
          if (NULL != pv)
          {
            t3 = *((threadPara*) pv);
          }
        }
```

---

As a side note: In C there is *no* need to cast to/from `void`-pointers from/to other pointers, the pointers involved get converted implicitly.

So this code

```
void* print_xs(void* unused){
    threadPara *tp = (threadPara *)unused;
    int i=tp->count;

    printf("Message from printxs %d %c\n", tp->count, tp->c);
    return (void*)tp;
}
```

may very well be written like this:

```
void* print_xs(void* unused){
    threadPara *tp = unused;
    int i=tp->count;

    printf("Message from printxs %d %c\n", tp->count, tp->c);
    return tp;
}
```